# add class to li with reference in jquery

Tags: jquery

i am working on a menu where i have a class in

here is my html

```
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li>
             <a href="http://localhost/final/?page_id=53">Comber Noil</a>
           </li>
           <li>
         <a href="http://localhost/final/?page_id=41" class="nav-active">Social</a>
           </li>
      </ul>
```

here is my jquery

```
           $(document).ready(function() {
          $('a.nav-active').parent().addClass('myclass');    
           });
```

Comment: Include jQuery and wrap your code in document ready, and remember to ask a question an validate your markup !

Comment: You have 1 `<li>` and 2 `</li>`...

Comment: sorry brain i edit my markup its like that in actual i put it wrong by mistake in question sorry again

Comment: here is the link http://www.paksoftsolutions.com/aktextile "what i want to do is when i select any menu item from dropdoen like about us so the parent(i.e About Us ) should also be highlighted "

Answer (score 2):

Your JavaScript looks correct (assuming you're waiting for a DOM ready event), but your markup is broken.  You need an opening `<li>` tag before your `.nav-active` link:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="http://localhost/final/?page_id=53">Comber Noil</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://localhost/final/?page_id=41" class="nav-active">Social</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

Edit: based on some of the comments below, it looks like what you want is that...

*When a user clicks a link inside the `.dropdown-menu`, you want to crawl back up to the root of the dropdown and add a `nav-active` class to the nested `a` element inside that `li`*?

Assuming so, here's the JavaScript to do that:

```
$('.dropdown-menu > li > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.dropdown').children('a').addClass('nav-active');
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: yes i edit my markup i made a mistake in question sorry for that

Comment: Hmm... based on your updated example, that should work ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QRwSu/)).  Any other factors in there that aren't apparent in the question?

Comment: so what is the solution then

Comment: I'm not sure... the code you've provided is correct.  Can you show us an example where it's failing?

Comment: Actually, I just saw the link you commented on your original question.  It looks like you want to add a `nav-active` class to the `a` element inside of the dropdown `ul.nav` when an item within the drop down is clicked?  I just want to verify, as that seems a little different from your original question.

Comment: Assuming that's a correct understanding, please see my modified answer.

Comment: no there is already nav-active class in <a tag but i want to add .myclass to the parent li of that <a and yes my question is little bit different from original as i tried to make it simple for better understanding

Comment: To the parent `li` of which `a`?  The one that was clicked, or the one  at the root of the dropdown?

Comment: the parent li of that <a which have class nav-active and this class nav-active apperes in that <a which is clicked you can check in the link given above that when you will click any link in drop down, nav-active class will be append to it.